# Function within Jquery not being seen

Tags: jquery, function, dom, typeerror, referenceerror

Hey all I have the following function that I am trying to call from a button click:

```
(function ($) {
  $(window).load(function() { 
     $("#status").fadeOut();
     $("#preloader").delay(400).fadeOut("slow");
     [Lots of code here]
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
     [Lots of code here]
  });

  [Lots of code here]

  function testing() {
     $("#status").fadeIn();
     $("#preloader").delay(400).fadeIn("slow");
  }

  [Lots of code here]
}(jQuery));
```

The error I get is:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: testing is not defined*

The HTML of the button I am using is:

```
<button value="TEST" onClick="testing();">test</button>
```

When I try placing the **testing()** code *outside* of the **(function ($) { }(jQuery));** it doesn't find the values for *status* and *preloader* having the error of this below on the **$("#status").fadeIn();** line:

*Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function*

I know the issue is around the **(function ($) { }(jQuery));** but I am unsure on how to go about being able to call it since this isn't my code.

Comment: you need to define the function in head section/before dom for button is loaded.

Comment: You need to stop using inline event handlers, problem solved !

Comment: when you place `testing()` outside, you're getting uncaught error on clicking button is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `testing` is inside jQuery scope. Your code should look like this:

```
function testing() {
   jQuery("#status").fadeIn();
   jQuery("#preloader").delay(400).fadeIn("slow");
}
(function ($) {
```

Comment: Doing it this way causes **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function** on **#status** like I said in my OP.

Comment: @StealthRT are you using `$("#status").fadeIn();` or `jQuery("#status").fadeIn();` as I have suggested?

Comment: Wow sorry. Overlooked that one. That does work once i use the **jQuery(...**. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<button value="TEST" onClick="testing();">test</button>
```

This code usually looks for `testing()` in global scope, anything within `<script>`tags but not inside in any function/object.

The problem with your code is that your Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) is actually defining a `testing()` function but there's no way to access it from the outside, its just a local variable within that IIFE. To make it available from you can return some object containing this function like this

```
        var myApp = (function ($) {
              $(window).load(function() { 

              });

              $(document).ready(function() {

              });

              // returning the object to call from outide   
              return { 
                testing : function () {
                  alert('sdfdfd');
                  $("#status").fadeIn();
                  $("#preloader").delay(400).fadeIn("slow");
                }
              }


            }(jQuery));
```

And you can call it like this from the button.

```
<button value="TEST" onClick="myApp.testing();">test</button>
```

Doing this, you won't pollute the global namespace with all your functions, you   can have all your functions defined in that returned object to call them from outside. This is how most libraries expose their API with a single global object :)